# In spherical geometry, are disks convex, and are chords internal to a circle?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

In Euclidean geometry, a chord of a circle is internal to the circle.  However, the proof of this relies on the External Angle Theorem, which does not hold for spherical geometry.

In spherical geometry:

- (Spherical) Circles are intersections of planes with spheres
- (Spherical) Lines are great circles
- (Spherical) Chords are segments of great circles

Can a spherical chord exit a spherical circle?

If yes: Can you provide an example?
If no: Can you prove this?

---

## Update

*As requested:*

Euclid proves in [Proposition III.2](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII2.html) that "If two points are taken at random on the circumference of a circle, then the straight line joining the points [i.e. chord] falls within the circle."  Visually, this seems obvious; but of course, it needs proof, which Euclid supplies.

Perhaps a more contemporary way of stating that is: *All disks are convex*, with a disk meaning *a circle and its interior* and the definition of convex being: *a region is convex if for any two points in the region, the segment between those two points is a subset of the region.*

So far, so good.  What about non-Euclidean geometry? Visually, this claim, that disks are convex, would seem to apply to spherical geometry as well.  I can think of no counterexample.  But Euclid's proof fails in spherical geometry!

Specifically, his proof makes use of the [exterior angle theorem](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI16.html), which does not apply to spherical geometry (see discussion [here](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI16.html)).  So, we have the following:

1. Visually, disks in spherical geometry appear to be convex
2. All examples of spherical disks I can think of are convex
3. Yet **the proof of convexity of the disk *fails* in spherical geometry**

That would suggest that either:

1. There's an alternate proof of the convexity of the disk that does *not* require the External Angle Theorem
2. There are spherical disk that are indeed not convex

I request either a proof of #1 or an example of #2.

Comment: Did you try to find examples yourself?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Certainly.  I wasn't able to.  But the only method I know of to find examples is to try to visualize a spherical circle, and to visualize a great circle intersecting it (at two points), and see in my mind's eye if it exited the circle between the two points of intersection.  None of them did.  I tried this for small circles and for the largest (ie boundaries of hemispheres).  Of course, the _external_ parts of the line are external to the circle, but that's true even in Euclidean.  I'm looking for examples where the chord goes out and back in.

Comment: Then draw pictures on paper, say, a longitudinal (even equatorial) circle and a full  meridional circle intersecting it. If you absolutely cannot draw pictures on paper, then buy an inflatable rubber balloon, pump some air into it and draw circles on the inflated balloon with a sharpie.

Comment: I don't understand your question. In the plane, a line intersects a circle generically at two points which divide the line into three parts. One part is internal to the circle and the other two are external to the circle. In spherical geometry, again there is generically two points of intersection and  the great circle is divided into only two parts. One is internal and the other external. What does "spherical chord exit a spherical circle" mean? Please explain this in your question by editing it.

Comment: @Somos.  Edited.  Thank you for the comment - it spurred me to realize the notion involved is _convexity of the disk_.

Comment: And how exactly would you define "the segment between those two points"? What does "between" mean axiomatically?

Comment: In spherical geometry there is no "the segment" between two points: There are always at least two such segments (sometimes, infinitely many).

Comment: According to [at least one source](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snew/pmath321-2021-S/LectureNotes/Chap2Spherical.pdf), a spherical disk may have a geodesic radius up to $\pi$; hence a circle cuts the sphere into two spherical disks. According to [another source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_convexity), the larger disk is not convex. Do you use the same definitions as these two sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a spherical disk that is non-convex:
[image: A sphere with a small circle drawn on it]
(Image courtesy of Wikipedia)

How? you may ask. That disk is clearly convex! you might protest. To which I say: Sure, the *small* one *inside* the circle is, but I'm talking about the *big* one *outside* the circle!

In spherical geometry, the plane is bounded, so the distinction between "inside" and "outside" disappears, and it must be specified for every closed curve. Intuitively, we use the smaller part when discussing the nature of shapes on spheres, because that's how it works in unbounded spaces, but we don't have to in bounded ones. And if we aren't careful to specify that we are, some pedant can come along and say we aren't.

This also applies to chords, by the way. Whatever great circle (intersecting the small one, of course. Back, pedants!) you draw on the above sphere, focusing on the smaller part will make the small disk "convex" and the big disk "concave", while the bigger part of the line will do the opposite, and suddenly the *small* disk is the "concave" one!

Answer (score 1):

It can happen topologically. On a plane, if you deform a circle into another circle and maintain the chord as a geodesic path between the endpoints, the chord remains internal to the circle. On a sphere, however, the deformation can cause the intended circle to pass through a great circle/line, so reversing orientation, and then the chord under this deformation is external to the reversed circle.